# Wordpress Woocommerce edit textfield in basket

Tags: wordpress, ftp, woocommerce

I work for a Company that has a website running in Wordpress. I have to edit a textfield in the basket of the website. Now I try to look into the ftp files,I can't find any file that matches with the textfield in the basket. I don't really have experience working with Wordpress.

I hope anyone could help me out ?

[image]

Comment: the textfield I have to edit is "verzendmethoden"

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to copy the mini-cart.php into yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/ not just yourtheme/woocommerce I can say for certain this works in Woocommerce version 2.0.12

Also if your saying that editing the core file isn't working is it possible that its getting override some where else in your theme. Could be worth searching your theme directory code for woocommerce_before_mini_cart seeing if thats used some where else.